# Scala: Iterating over a Future of list of tuples containing lists as well. Need a final result of Future of tuple

Tags: scala, fold

I have a val assume

```
val a: Future[List[(List[Case_Class], List[Case_Class])]] = //some method call
```

In my tuple, there are two lists, say

```
listA = List[Case_Class] and listB = List[Case_Class].
```

Both the lists are having two elements at a time. What I need is applying some logic(ex: fold) to my val 'a' so as to achieve

```
Future[(List(Case_Class), List(Case_Class))]
```

What should be the logic that I must apply?

Comment: `a.map(_.head)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
a.map(_.unzip match { case (x, y) => (x.flatten, y.flatten) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse the unruly number of brackets in the below example but this seems to work:

```
case class Thing()

val a: Future[List[(List[Thing], List[Thing])]] = {
  Future.successful(List((List(Thing()), List(Thing()))))
}

val b: Future[(List[Thing], List[Thing])] = {
  a.map(x => (x.unzip._1.flatten, x.unzip._2.flatten))
}

Await.ready(b, Duration.Inf)
// scala.concurrent.Future[(List[Thing], List[Thing])] =
// Future(Success((List(Thing()),List(Thing()))))
```

More on `unzip` [here](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/scala-unzip-example).